# SpeechRecognition emitting network error event in Brave Browser

Tags: javascript, microphone, brave

I am seeing a `network` error when I am trying to use the [SpeechRecognition API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) in Brave. It's working just fine in Chrome and Safari in OS X. Is that simply not working in Brave or is there a way to make it work? Please have a look at the jsfiddle below for a 'working' example. I would have expected `SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition` to be `undefined` if Speech Recognition is not supported.

```js
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.lang = "en-US";
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.interimResults = true;

recognition.start();

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += event.results[0][0].transcript;
}
recognition.onstart = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += '-start-' ;
}

recognition.onerror = function(event) { 
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += `-error ${event.error}-` ;
}

recognition.onend = function(event) {
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += '-end-' ; 

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qomdcL6g/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you discovered, the `SpeechRecognition` API is not currently supported in the Brave browser. A Brave developer explained this in [a GitHub issue comment on the official Brave repository](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3725#issuecomment-555694620):

> First of all: this isn't a problem with the microphone — it's a speech
> recognition API. Chrome ships with a non-standard API used for speech
> recognition. Websites which call the API are asking the browser to
> transcribe audio on behalf of the website and send the site the
> transcribed text (not the audio). When a site calls this API in
> Chrome, Chrome sends the raw audio to a Google server for
> transcription. The Google server parses the raw audio, and send the
> transcribed text back to Chrome. Chrome then passes the text to the
> website.
>
> There are two problems with this. The simple straightforward problem
> is that Brave doesn't have access to that Google transcription
> service. It's a paid service from Google which Chrome gets to use for
> free. If Brave wanted to use it, we'd have to pay Google for the
> privilege. The second and much more substantial issue is that I don't
> think that anyone reasonably expects clicking a microphone icon on
> Duolingo to result in Brave sending their audio to Google.
>
> Honestly, I think that this design in Chrome is absolutely ridiculous
> and I was completely flabbergasted when I learned how it worked. We've
> had some conversations with Google about it, and the outcome is more
> or less (1) that they don't see what the issue is, and (2) they won't
> give us access to this online transcription service unless we pay for
> it.

Without developer support for a Brave-specific implementation of the API in question, it will not function as it does in more popular browsers.

To your question about why `SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition` is truthy, it's likely because the Chromium core for Brave is returning something that would indicate support.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I wish they simply could disable the feature in Brave to clarify that for developers.